# How to keep the same content in html even when refreshed or deleted

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a to-do list with javascript and I want the to-do list to keep data even when the page is refreshed or deleted, I am new to javascript so bear with me and please keep your answer nice and simple and without jquery and all that stuff if possible.
Regards.

Comment: Store it in localstorage

Comment: You have to store it somewhere and there are several options for that, some are simpler than others (cookies, localStorage, server-side database). It all depends on your application requirements.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @MuathAlhazmi! When asking for assistance, it's preferred you show us what you're trying to do by including code snippets you've written. This helps us point out improvements and let's us see how much research you've done on your own before posting.

Comment: ok i am sorry i will do next time